# QGIS doesn't recognize GRASS commands

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

When I try to use GRASS commands in QGIS, I get the following error message:

> Missing dependency.This algorithm cannot be run :-(  This algorithm
> requires GRASS to be run. Unfortunately, it seems that GRASS is not
> installed in your system, or it is not correctly configured to be used
> from QGIS Click here to know more about how to install and configure
> GRASS to be used with QGIS

I'm not sure if this is related, but in processing options and configuration I have the following paths:

> Grass Folder: C:/PROGRA~2/QGISCH~1/apps\grass\grass-6.4.4
>
> MSYS Folder: C:/PROGRA~2/QGISCH~1/apps\msys

Should I reroute these folders? Which are the correct folders that Grass folder and MSYS folder should point towards?

Comment: Can you double-click on the paths to update them to your installation?

Answer (score 2):

As Markus wrote, it is a simple setting in:

Processing -> Processing options -> Providers -> GRASS ...

On Windows, correct folders are - with the path to your OSGeo / QGIS-installation as a basis:

apps\grass\grass-YOUR-VERSION

MSYS is no longer required for GRASS 7 on Windows.